# building several targets using for loops in gnu make (only symbol definitions change)

Tags: for-loop, gnu-make, debug-symbols

i need to build 4 targets from the same set of source files.
The only thing that changes are a couple of symbol definitios at compile time (-D DEBUG_OUTPUT, -D TIME_OUTPUT)

how can I accomplish that in a GNU makefile?

I thought of running a gnu make 'for loop' and re-declare the $(SYMBOLS) and $(TARGETNAME) each time, then run make $(TARGETNAME) from within the for loop.

Is that possible?
Is there a better way (preferrably using gnu make and not automake, or some other variant)

Thank you,
nass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
foo: DEBUG_OUTPUT=yes
foo: TIME_OUTPUT=2

bar: DEBUG_OUTPUT=no
bar: TIME_OUTPUT=3

baz: DEBUG_OUTPUT=maybe
baz: TIME_OUTPUT=5

qux: DEBUG_OUTPUT=dunno
qux: TIME_OUTPUT=7

TARGETS = foo bar baz qux

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): $(SOURCE_FILES)
    @echo compile $^ into $@ using $(DEBUG_OUTPUT) and $(TIME_OUTPUT)
```

Comment: unless i misinterepreted you , what you say only works for the 1st declaration of the variables, for all the targets. (here 
    foo: DEBUG_OUTPUT=yes
    foo: TIME_OUTPUT=2
)

Comment: yes. you see I declare targets as you stated, and added symbol declarations (-D,-U) prefixing the target names. then i declared sources and objects etc. then i define the generic $(TARGETS): $(OBJECTS) . The problem is that $(OBJECTS) is another (multi)target, where the objects are compiled from the source files. As such the $(TARGETS) is executable for all targets but $(OBJECTS) only once, thus the code is compiled once but is linked as many times as there are targets.so the variable declarations (that I call for from the $(OBJECTS) target definition, are only resolved on the 1st access.

Comment: any ideas how to circumvent that?

Comment: @nass, you should have said so in the question. There are several solutions. The simplest is to do without `$(OBJECTS)`, if the language allows it. Otherwise you must decide whether you want the objects built with different symbol definitions to have the same names and/or be put in the same place.

Comment: i'd prefer the later, how do I go about it? Thank you

Comment: @nass: "the later"? *What do you mean?*

Comment: I'd prefer to try the later (2nd) solution, not the former. i.e. i'd prefer to keep the $(OBJECTS) target.

Comment: Either you're not reading what I write, or you can't decide. Either way I can't help you.